# JS LightBox - Simulate mouse click in Lightbox, but document.click() doesn't activate Lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox, lightbox2

## Background

The higher idea is that I'm trying to use voice commands to control my webpage. I receive a message to do something, and I try to simulate that programatically. (ie, clicking on a button or typing something in).

Right now, I have a Lightbox gallery (using source code from (https://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/?) with images in it. There is a single div container with anchor elements and images elements in the anchors.

```
<doctype = HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = 'stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = 'text/css' href = 'css/lightbox.min.css'>
        <script src = 'js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js'></script>
        <title>Image Gallery</title>
        <meta name = 'viewport' content = 'width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "Gallery" id = 'gallery'>
            <a id = 'image 1' href = "http://placekitten.com/200/300" data-lightbox = 'mygallery' ><img src = "http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
            <a id = 'image 2' href = "http://placekitten.com/200/300" data-lightbox = 'mygallery' ><img src = "http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
            <a id = 'image 3' href = "http://placekitten.com/200/300" data-lightbox = 'mygallery' ><img src = "http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
            <a id = 'image 4' href = "http://placekitten.com/200/300" data-lightbox = 'mygallery' ><img src = "http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
            <a id = 'image 5' href = "http://placekitten.com/200/300" data-lightbox = 'mygallery' ><img src = "http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
        </div>
    </body>
```

This is what is looks like initially. [On page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCnJQ.png)

And this is what it looks like when I click on one of the images. [On image click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uufax.png)

## Issue

Now when I receive a message (from a voice command) to click on an image, I run something like:

```
document.getElementById('image1').click()
```

However, when I do that, it takes me to the actual url of the image, "http://placekitten.com/200/300", instead of doing the whole Lightbox thing.

With my limited knowledge of HTML and JS, the Lightbox script will create an onclick event listener, that will instantiate a new 'Lightbox' when you click on an image. I'm confused as to why a regular mouse click will launch a new Lightbox, but a document.getElement.click() does not.

## Questions

- How is a mouse click different from document.getElement.click()?
- Why is this not working?...lol

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It has to do with Event propagation.

The images are child nodes of anchor nodes. When you do document.getElementById('id').click(), then it activates the event listener for the image, but then click event then bubbles up to the top element, which is the anchor element, which then redirects me to the link in the anchor (even though it's just supposed to act as a thumbnail).

You can stop the event propagation with a `stopPropagation()` or `stopImmediatePropagation()` call in an event listener, or you can do `event.preventDefault()`.

My follow-up issue to this discovery is that the Lightbox library was too complicated for me to understand to go and modify the event listeners to prevent event bubbling.